# How do I stop a previous Thread that is listening to kafka-topic

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka

Lets say I have a threads running with unique names(set by me), now i want to create one more thread with same name which already exist. How do i kill/stop the older thread? Here is my code to identify if thread with same name exist:

```
 Set<Thread> processes = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
  processes.forEach(process -> {
    if (process.getName().equals(eventConfiguration.getId().toString())) {
      System.out.println("Yes Does Exit");
      
      process.interrupt();
    }
  });

  Thread t = new Thread(eventConfigurationThreads);
  t.setName(eventConfiguration.getId().toString());
  t.start();
```

In this run method I am killing/not starting the newest thread, but i want to start new thread and kill the old thread with same name.

```
 @Override
public void run() {
while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
  try {
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = anomalyConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
    if (!records.isEmpty()) {

      EventProcessHandler eventProcessHandler = new EventProcessHandler(delegateExecution,
          runtimeService);

      eventProcessHandler
          .recordArrived(records, Thread.currentThread().getId(), configurationRecord);
      anomalyConsumer.commitAsync();
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    try {
      anomalyConsumer.close();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
    }

  }
}
```

When i am trying to execute the above code, and calling the interrupt method, I am getting Interrupted Exception, How do i handle this.

Comment: 1. Your isExit doesn't allow to stop the consumer really immediately. 100 millis should work as "almost" immediately, but doesn't seem to be optimal/reasonable. Canonical way looks like (just googled) stackoverflow.com/questions/62375919/… 2. I'd strongly recommend to don't try to find a Thread by its name (and don't lean on thread's name at all, except debugging/monitoring purposes), just store a reference to the thread and stop its run() (as described, with a flag and wakeup() or by Thread.interrupt()) and then do Thread.join() if required (to guarantee the method run() is out).

Comment: If you use ExecutorService, store a reference to the submitted Runnable as a Future and call Future.cancel(true) to stop the consuming

Comment: @AnatolyG Thanks for your response, I have made an edit to the question, can you please suggest some solution to it. How do I use Join method in this scenario?

Comment: I also would like to know why do you need to re-instantiate/re-run a consuming thread? What are you trying to achieve that way?

Comment: Well, I am having a thread that is listening to some topic and gets some configuration, when an update is made to the configuration it is pushed to a Kafka-topic, now my earlier thread which is having an older configuration should be dead and a newer thread should be run with newer configuration, that i just received.

Comment: We are so close...) So, you are replacing a consumer with the same eventConfiguration.getId(), right? And what type is that eventConfiguration.getId(), btw?

Comment: It is an integer type @AnatolyG

Comment: Does the thread do anything else except consuming updated configuration and re-running itself? Do it process any business records consumed from the same topic? What is the configuration about? Does it contain business logic parameters to be applied to business records OR/AND specifies what server/topic should be consumed. If the config is only about business logic parameters, not about Kafka topic related things, why we need to stop/interrupt the thread? If the config says "now switch to server 192.168.45.4:9662 topic "mytopic4", then re-creating of the thread is a reasonable thing.

Comment: Could you please answer these questions and I'll suggest you some code to deal with this stuff. 2 main principles are going to be reflected in the code: single responsibility/separation of concerns (we will extract consumer management code to separate class/thread) + closeable topic consumer

Comment: Well the concept is from the UI, I get some configuration for a sensor, and the configuration has some business configuration as well, so whenever I am getting a new configuration I am creating a thread asking it to listen to a different topic, In this topic I am actually be getting some sensor data related to the configuration. Now lets say the configuration has been updated and pushed to event-config topic, now current code will actually create a new thread which actually listens to sensors, but since the old thread is not stopped yet, in case of anomaly i will be actually raising two events

Comment: Contd... This should not happen in reality, the older configuration thread should be stopped, and the newest thread should be active since the older thread is listening to a topic. The reason, why the database is not used to fetch configuration, is to loosely couple services. Event Config is just one kafka consumer, the threads which are being created based on configuration, will be listening to same topic but with different group-id. While closing the consumer which is listening to Sensor topic, i am facing issue.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, there are many possible solutions to meet your requirements. I'd try the following (this is just a draft, feel free to try and change)...

1. We are going to consume both configurations and anomalies, so, let's introduce some generic Topic consumer which has come required mechanism to be stopped (closed) and its listener:

```java
    public interface TopicEventListener {
        void onEvent(byte[] key, byte[] event) throws Exception;
    }
   

    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
    import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
    import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer;
    
    import java.time.Duration;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Properties;
    
    public class Topic implements AutoCloseable {
        private final TopicConfig topicConfig;
    
        private final Consumer consumer;
    
        public Topic(final TopicConfig topicConfig) {
            this.topicConfig = topicConfig;
    
            final Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, topicConfig.getBootstrapServers());
            // this is a common topic consumer, so we just pull byte arrays and pass them
            // to a listener, we don't do any decoding in here
            props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class.getName());
            props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArraySerializer.class.getName());
            // ... all other required properties are here ...
    
            consumer = new org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer<>(props);
            try {
                consumer.partitionsFor(topicConfig.getTopic()); // just to check connectivity immediately
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                try {
                    consumer.close();
                } catch (final Exception ignore) {
                }
                throw e;
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * We can exit from this method only by an exception. Most important cases:
         * 1. org.apache.kafka.common.errors.WakeupException - if we call close() method
         * 2. org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InterruptException - if the current thread has
         * been interrupted
         * @see KafkaConsumer#poll(Duration)
         *
         * @param listener
         */
        public void consumeUntilError(final TopicEventListener listener) {
            consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(topicConfig.getTopic()));
    
            while (true) {
                final ConsumerRecords<byte[], byte[]> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
                for (ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record : records) {
                    try {
                        listener.onEvent(record.key(), record.value());
                    } catch (final InterruptedException e) { // can be thrown by a blocking operation inside onEvent()
                        throw new org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InterruptException(e);
                    } catch (final Exception e) {
                        // just log ("Unexpected error while listener.onEvent() notification", e)
                        // don't corrupt the consuming loop because of
                        // an error in a listener
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void close() {
            try {
                consumer.wakeup();
            } finally {
                consumer.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

2. Now, let's make a thread which uses the Topic to consume the data and to implement re-connect (failover) functionality and its listener:

```java
    public interface TopicConsumerListener extends TopicEventListener {
        void onStarted();
    
        void onStoppedByErrorAndReconnecting(Exception error);
    
        void onStopped();
    }

    public class TopicConsumer {
        private final TopicConfig topicConfig;
    
        private ConsumingThread consumingThread; // guarded by this
        private boolean closed; // guarded by this
    
        public TopicConsumer(final TopicConfig topicConfig) {
            this.topicConfig = topicConfig;
        }
    
        public synchronized void start(final TopicConsumerListener listener) {
            if (closed) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Closed");
            }
    
            if (consumingThread != null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Already started");
            }
    
            final ConsumingThread ct = new ConsumingThread(listener);
            ct.start();
            consumingThread = ct;
        }
    
        public void stop() throws InterruptedException {
            final ConsumingThread ct;
            synchronized (this) {
                ct = consumingThread;
    
                if (ct == null) {
                    return;
                }
    
                consumingThread = null;
            }
    
            ct.close();
    
            if (Thread.currentThread() != ct) {
                ct.join();
            }
        }
    
        public void close() throws InterruptedException {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (closed) {
                    return;
                }
                closed = true;
            }
    
            stop();
        }
    
        private class ConsumingThread extends Thread {
            private final TopicConsumerListener listener;
            private volatile boolean closed;
    
            ConsumingThread(final TopicConsumerListener listener) {
                super("Consumer#" + topicConfig.getBootstrapServers() + "/" + topicConfig.getTopic());
                this.listener = listener;
            }
    
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Exception error = null;
    
                while (true) {
                    Topic tc = null;
                    try {
                        tc = new Topic(topicConfig);
    
                        try {
                            listener.onStarted();
                        } catch (final Exception e) {
                            // log ("Unexpected error while onStarted() notification", e);
                        }
    
                        // we consume the events from the topic until
                        // this thread is interrupted by close()
                        tc.consumeUntilError(listener);
                    } catch (final Exception e) {
                        if (closed) {
                            break;
                        }
                        error = e;
                    } finally {
                        if (tc != null) {
                            try {
                                tc.close();
                            } catch (final Exception ignore) {
                            }
                        }
                    }
    
                    try {
                        listener.onStoppedByErrorAndReconnecting(error);
                    } catch (final Exception e) {
                        //log ("Unexpected error while onStoppedByErrorAndReconnecting() notification", e)
                    }
    
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000); // TODO: make the timeout configurable and use backoff with jitter
                    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                        break; // interrupted by close()
                        // we don't restore the flag interrupted, since we still need
                        // to do some additional work like
                        // to notify listener.onStopped()
                    }
                }
    
                try {
                    listener.onStopped();
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    //log ("Unexpected error while onStoppedByErrorAndReconnecting() notification", e);
                }
            }
    
            void close() {
                if (closed) { // no atomicity/membars required
                    return; // since can be called only by one single thread
                }
                closed = true;
    
                // We stop the consuming with org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InterruptException
                // In here it isn't convenient to call Topic.close() directly to initiate
                // org.apache.kafka.common.errors.WakeupException, since we recreate
                // the instance of Topic and it takes additional efforts to share the
                // changeable reference to a Topic to close it from other thread.
                interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
```

3. By now, we can consume byte arrays from a Kafka topic with failover. It's time to use a work queue pattern to manage our configurable consumers. The class has a thread which uses a blocking queue to receive commands to be executed (with configurations included). Note, this is IMPORTANT. One single thread to manage instances and their states prevents any possible race conditions. If a consumer with the same ID has been already started, we close it and only then we start new consumer:

```java
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
    import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

    public class TopicConsumerManager {
        private final CommandExecutor commandExecutor;

        private volatile BlockingQueue<Object> commands = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(10_000); // some reasonable limit
        // just to prevent possible OOM

        public TopicConsumerManager() {
            commandExecutor = new CommandExecutor(commands);
            commandExecutor.start();
        }

        public void execute(final Object command) throws InterruptedException {
            final BlockingQueue<Object> cms = commands;
            if (cms == null) { // closed
                return;
            }
            cms.put(command);
        }

        public void close() throws InterruptedException {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (commands == null) {
                    return;
                }
                commands = null;
            }

            commandExecutor.interrupt();

            if (Thread.currentThread() != commandExecutor) {
                commandExecutor.join();
            }
        }

        private class CommandExecutor extends Thread {
            private final Map<Integer, TopicConsumer> consumers = new HashMap<>();
            private final BlockingQueue<Object> commands;

            public CommandExecutor(final BlockingQueue<Object> commands) {
                super("TopicConsumerManager");
                this.commands = commands;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        final Object command = commands.take();
                        try {
                            if (command instanceof MakeTopicConsumer) {
                                final MakeTopicConsumer makeTc = (MakeTopicConsumer) command;

                                final TopicConsumer oldTc = consumers.get(makeTc.getConfig().getId());
                                if (oldTc != null) {
                                    oldTc.close();
                                }

                                final TopicConsumer newTc = new TopicConsumer(makeTc.getConfig());
                                consumers.put(makeTc.getConfig().getId(), newTc);

                                newTc.start(makeTc.getListener());
                            }
                        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                            throw e; // push the exception up to break the loop
                        } catch (final Exception e) {
                            // log ("An error while executing: " + command, e)
                        }
                    }
                } catch (final InterruptedException ignore) {
                    // we don't need to restore interrupted() flag, since
                    // we need to do additional job - to close
                    // all started consumers
                } finally {
                    // close all existing consumers
                    for (TopicConsumer tc : consumers.values()) {
                        try {
                            tc.close();
                        } catch (final Exception ignore) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

4. Our structures are:

```
    public class TopicConfig {
        private String bootstrapServers;
        private String topic;
    
        public TopicConfig() {
        }
    
        public TopicConfig(final String bootstrapServers, final String topic) {
            this.bootstrapServers = bootstrapServers;
            this.topic = topic;
        }
    
        public String getBootstrapServers() {
            return bootstrapServers;
        }
    
        public void setBootstrapServers(final String bootstrapServers) {
            this.bootstrapServers = bootstrapServers;
        }
    
        public String getTopic() {
            return topic;
        }
    
        public void setTopic(final String topic) {
            this.topic = topic;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getClass().getSimpleName() +
                    " bootstrapServers='" + bootstrapServers + '\'' +
                    ", topic='" + topic + '\'';
        }
    }
    
    public class IdentifiableTopicConfig extends TopicConfig {
        private int id;
    
        public IdentifiableTopicConfig() {
        }
    
        public IdentifiableTopicConfig(final int id, final String bootstrapServers, final String topic) {
            super(bootstrapServers, topic);
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(final int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() +
                    ", id=" + id;
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * A command
     */
    public class MakeTopicConsumer {
        private final IdentifiableTopicConfig config;
        private final TopicConsumerListener listener;
    
        public MakeTopicConsumer(final IdentifiableTopicConfig config, final TopicConsumerListener listener) {
            this.config = config;
            this.listener = listener;
        }
    
        public IdentifiableTopicConfig getConfig() {
            return config;
        }
    
        public TopicConsumerListener getListener() {
            return listener;
        }
    }
```

5. Now, let's use some glue...

```
    public class Application {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            // initial parameters to start listening to the configs
            final String configBootstrapServers = args[0];
            final String configTopic = args[1];
    
            final TopicConsumerManager topicManager = new TopicConsumerManager();
            final TopicConsumer configConsumer = new TopicConsumer(
                    new TopicConfig(configBootstrapServers,configTopic));
    
            configConsumer.start(new TopicConsumerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStarted() {
                    System.out.println("Config consuming started.");
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onStoppedByErrorAndReconnecting(final Exception error) {
                    System.out.println("Config consuming stopped by error: " +
                                error.getLocalizedMessage() + " and reconnecting...");
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onStopped() {
                    System.out.println("Config consuming stopped.");
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onEvent(final byte[] key, final byte[] event) throws Exception {
                    final IdentifiableTopicConfig config = new IdentifiableTopicConfig();
                    // decode and fill-in IdentifiableTopicConfig from event bytes
    
                    System.out.println("Configuration consumed: " + config);
    
                    topicManager.execute(new MakeTopicConsumer(config, new TopicConsumerListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onStarted() {
                            System.out.println("Consuming for " + config + " started.");
                        }
    
                        @Override
                        public void onStoppedByErrorAndReconnecting(final Exception error) {
                            System.out.println("Consuming for " + config + " stopped by error: " + error.getLocalizedMessage() + " and reconnecting...");
                        }
    
                        @Override
                        public void onStopped() {
                            System.out.println("Consuming for " + config + " stopped.");
                        }
    
                        @Override
                        public void onEvent(final byte[] key, final byte[] event) {
                            System.out.println("An event consumed for " + config + '.');
                            // ... process your event ...
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });

            configConsumer.close();
            topicManager.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey AnatolyG, this answers part of my question and I am working on the solution you provided, can you share your email, so that i can you send you the project for review!

Comment: @LuciferGeralt, Q1:"How do i kill/stop the older thread?" A1: Just store a reference to the Thread which makes the pooling loop and call Consumer.wakeup() or just Thread.interrupt() for that Thread. Q2:"I am getting Interrupted Exception, How do i handle this" A2:In details it depends... But in any case you exit from the polling loop and close the consumer, since you are going to stop the consuming. What if you just share the code with github, google drive etc?